# EntityManagerFactory is null using Springboot and Elide

Tags: java, spring-boot, json-api

I am trying to get a JSON API-compliant RESTful service working with Spring Boot and Elide by following this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-json-api-rest-service-with-spring-boot-an
and this example code: https://github.com/mcasperson/spring-boot-jpa-elide/

But EntityManagerFactory is null at this line: https://github.com/mcasperson/spring-boot-jpa-elide/blob/master/src/main/java/com/matthewcasperson/elidetest/ElideTest.java#L60

I'm not sure how to trouble shoot the @Autowired annotation: https://github.com/mcasperson/spring-boot-jpa-elide/blob/master/src/main/java/com/matthewcasperson/elidetest/ElideTest.java#L31-L32
to figure out why the EntityManagerFactory is `null`.

Any ideas what sort of things I can try to troubleshoot this?  I'm new to the Java world so I'm a bit lost.

My app didn't have a database but I added a H2 database just in case it mattered for the EntityManagerFactory.

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Do you have the a db as specified in the application properties (ports, url etc)?

Comment: Also check your server logs at the time of starting your App, it would be throwing exceptions if DB is not correctly configured.

Comment: Thanks (sorry can’t tag more than one user) for the advice. My coworker was able to help me through this one. I’ll post his findings after the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the method using the `EntityManagerFactory` needs to have a particular signature in order for the `@Autowired` annotation to work.

So this line affect the `@Autowired` annotation:
https://github.com/mcasperson/spring-boot-jpa-elide/blob/master/src/main/java/com/matthewcasperson/elidetest/ElideTest.java#L49

Hope that helps other Java newbies like me :)